# save user input data in kivy and store for later use/analysis python

Tags: python, kivy

I am a kivy n00b, using python, and am not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Can someone please explain how a user can input data in an Android app, and how/where it is stored (SQL table, csv, xml?). I am also confused as to how it can be extended/used for further analysis.

I think it should be held as a SQL table, but do not understand how to save/set up a SQL table in an android app, nor how to access it. Similarly, how to save/append/access a csv/xml document, nor how if these are made, how they are secure from accidental deletion, overwriting, etc

In essence, I want to save only the timestamp a user enters some data, and the corresponding values (max 4).

User input would consist of 4 variables, `x1, x2, x3, x4`, and I would write a SQL statement along the lines: `insert into data.table timestamp, x1, x2, x3, x4`, and then to access the data something along the lines of `select * from data.table` and then do/show stuff.

Can someone offer suggestions on what resources to read? How to set up a SQL Server table in an android app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works basically the same way on android as on the desktop: you have access to the local filesystem to create/edit files (at least within the app directory), so you can read and write whatever data storage format you like.

If you want to use a database, sqlite is the simplest and most obvious option.